# Criteria to order two different students classes's marks

Tags: statistics

I have two classes with 40 students each.

Each class represent a different speciality ( one is topology class and the other is fields theory class)

Every student has a mark from 0 to 20, the problem is that i have a list of subjects and i want to order the student with respect to their marks to choose a subject. But the topology class is harder than the fields theory class so their marks is lower. So i don't to order only based on marks without doing some operations on these marks.

So is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: This is not clear.  At a guess:  you want to compare students in two different classes, knowing that the distribution of grades is not the same in each class.  If that's right, I'd suggest using $\sigma $ units...if one student is one standard deviation above the mean in class $A$ and another is $2$ standard deviations above the mean in class $B$ you could say that the second student is better (in some sense).

Comment: At worst, it sounds like you are trying to compare [apples to oranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges).

Comment: Yes your guess is right, i want to compare students in different classes, your comment was the first thing i could think of, by calculating the difference between every mark and the mean of the corresponding class. Would that be fair enough?

Comment: "fair" can't be determined from the given data.  But I can't see anything better than this, if all you have is the raw grades.

Comment: I think the best way would be what lulu suggested in the first comment. You could also take in mind the rank(1st,2nd,...) of each student in their class(assuming the two classes have equally "good" students).

Comment: @lulu and should i divise on the standard deviation of each class?

Comment: I think it's enough to just use sigma units.

Comment: To clarify:  $\sigma$ units already divide by the standard deviation.  That is, if a student in class $A$ gets a score of $X$ then you compute $\frac {x-\mu_A}{\sigma_A}$ where $\mu_A$ is the mean score in class $A$ and $\sigma_A$ is the standard deviation of the scores in class $A$.

Comment: Thank you so much.